# Schwänzl and Vogt, Cofibration and fibration structures in enriched categories

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, model-categories

In [Schwänzl and Vogt, *Strong cofibrations and fibrations in enriched categories*], the authors refer to an earlier preprint, [Schwänzl and Vogt, *Cofibration and fibration structures in enriched categories*] but give a URL that no longer works. Is this preprint still available somewhere online?

(It seems the preprint deals with some of complications arising from the fact that there is no "good" cylinder object in the category of simplicial sets. The later paper omits these details.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is also available here:
https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/sfb343/preprints/pr97044.ps.gz